# Install kibana patch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am not able to export documents to csv from discovery tab. I tried to install the kibana patch that I found here...

https://github.com/fbaligand/kibana/releases

But there are no clear instructions about how to install it.

---

I got this link from the github issue.

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1992

how to install kibana patch?

Answer (score 0):

After applying the patch run the following command while in kibana directory.

```
rm -fr optimize
```

Now restart kibana.